# How can I query the weekday average of published articles in a monogdb document?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm using the [New York Times Articles & Comments (2020) dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/benjaminawd/new-york-times-articles-comments-2020) and I want to generate the average of published articels per weekday for the whole year like so:

Mo: 50
Tu: 60
Wed: 40
...

So far I managed to query the articles count for each day in the dataset for the whole year and sort it:

```js
db.nyt_art.aggregate(
    [
        { $group: {
            _id: {
                year: { $year: "$pub_date" },
                month: { $month: "$pub_date" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$pub_date" }
                
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
        },
        {$sort: {_id: -1}}
    ]
)
```

```js
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 31
    },
    "count": 35
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 30
    },
    "count": 53
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 29
    },
    "count": 47
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 28
    },
    "count": 49
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 27
    },
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 26
    },
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 25
    },
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 24
    },
    "count": 41
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 23
    },
    "count": 72
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 22
    },
    "count": 59
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 21
    },
    "count": 50
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 20
    },
    "count": 21
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 19
    },
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 18
    },
    "count": 47
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 17
    },
    "count": 61
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 16
    },
    "count": 58
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 15
    },
    "count": 70
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 14
    },
    "count": 53
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 13
    },
    "count": 11
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "year": 2020,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 12
    },
    "count": 17
  }
]
```

Now I'm stuck as I don't know how to get the average article output on each weekday.

UPDATE:

I managed to get the results I wanted but as I'm new to mongodb, I'm not sure if I did it the correct and best way. Here is what I did:

```js
// Average of articles published per weekday
db.nyt_art.aggregate(
    [
        // First Stage
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    year: { $year: "$pub_date" },
                    month: { $month: "$pub_date" },
                    day: { $dayOfMonth: "$pub_date" },
                    weekday: { $dayOfWeek: "$pub_date" }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
        },
        // Second Stage
        {
            $group: {
              _id: { wd: "$_id.weekday"},
              total_on_wd: {
                $sum: "$count"
              },
              total_wds: {
                $sum: "$_id.weekday"
              }
            }
        },
        // Third Stage
        {
            $project: {
              _id: { wd: "$_id.wd"},
              avg_wd: {
                $divide: ["$total_on_wd", 52]
              }
              }
            
        },
        // Fourth Stage
        {$sort: {_id: 1}}
    ]
)
```

And the results:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "wd": 1
    },
    "avg_wd": 16.634615384615383
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "wd": 2
    },
    "avg_wd": 52.78846153846154
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "wd": 3
    },
    "avg_wd": 62.53846153846154
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "wd": 4
    },
    "avg_wd": 63.30769230769231
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "wd": 5
    },
    "avg_wd": 61.30769230769231
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "wd": 6
    },
    "avg_wd": 49.21153846153846
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "wd": 7
    },
    "avg_wd": 17.03846153846154
  }
]
```

Is this actually delivering the correct results? Also I'm not sure on how to count how often each day has occuret in that year (right now I'm just using a constant of 52 days of each weekday per year).

Comment: First you need to find a way to tell which weekday is each day. Take a look at $dayOfWeek. Then you have to sum all the counts of all items with same day of week and divide by the number of days, which would be the days between the initial date and final date divided by 7.

Comment: Actually the number of days shouln't be calculated that way because that would work if the final date was one weekday sooner than the initial date.

Comment: @Adrian I've tried do what you suggested and updated the post with the results, could you check if it did it correctly?

Comment: I don't really know mongodb, but I can tell you the result must be wrong. I've created some Javascript code to check the result and in Monday I got 45.6666 but you got 16.63. Also keep in mind that the only data I used was the json you posted in the second code snippet.